# How to phrase a T-SQL horizontal join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database which is including two tables, Labs and LabUsers
How do I join a column from `LabUsers` into a cell in `Labs`.

To be specific, I would like to have the user names of a lab to be concatenated and separated with a bullet ( `• is Alt+0149`), and to have these usernames sorted alphabetically left to right.

Here is an example.

The `Labs` table looks like this:

```
LabID  LabName     LabStudents
-----  ----------  -----------
1      North       NULL
2      North East  NULL
3      South West  NULL
```

and the `LabUsers` looks like this:

```
LabUserID   LabUserName   LabID
---------   -----------   -----    
1           Diana         1
2           Paul          2
3           Paula         2
4           Romeo         1
5           Julia         1
6           Rose          2
7           Diana         2
```

I would like to get this outcome in the `Labs` table:

```
LabID  LabName     LabUsers
-----  ----------  ---------------------
1      North       Diana•Julia•Romeo
2      North East  Diana•Paul•Paula•Rose
3      South West  NULL
```

Here is the script to create the tables:

```
USE [tempdb];
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LabUsers]
(
    [LabUserID] [int] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [LabUserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LabID] [int] NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] SELECT 1, N'Diana', 1;
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] SELECT 2, N'Paul',  2;
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] SELECT 3, N'Paula', 2;
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] SELECT 4, N'Romeo', 1;
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] SELECT 5, N'Julia', 1;
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] SELECT 6, N'Rose',  2;
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] SELECT 7, N'Diana', 2;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Labs]
(
    [LabID] [int] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [LabName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LabUsers] [nvarchar](max) NULL
);
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Labs] SELECT 1, N'North',      NULL;
INSERT [dbo].[Labs] SELECT 2, N'North East', NULL;
INSERT [dbo].[Labs] SELECT 3, N'South West', NULL;
```

Comment: Any reason you can't do this in code?

Comment: Abe Miessler- I do. But I would like to have it as a stored procedure due to collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT l.LabID, l.LabName, LabUsers = STUFF((SELECT N'•' + lu.LabUserName
  FROM dbo.LabUsers AS lu 
  WHERE lu.LabID = l.LabID
  ORDER BY lu.LabUserName
  FOR XML PATH(''), 
  TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')
FROM dbo.Labs AS l;
```

I see absolutely no reason to store this in the table, since you can always generate the code at runtime when you run a query. If you store it in the table, then you have to update it every single time you change any row in the table.

However, if I can't convince you not to do this (it really is bad to store redundant data like this), you can try this way:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT l.LabID, l.LabName, x = STUFF((SELECT N'•' + lu.LabUserName
      FROM dbo.LabUsers AS lu 
      WHERE lu.LabID = l.LabID
      ORDER BY lu.LabUserName
      FOR XML PATH(''), 
      TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')
    FROM dbo.Labs AS l
)
UPDATE l
SET LabUsers = x.x
FROM dbo.Labs AS l
INNER JOIN x ON l.LabID = x.LabID;
```

As for the performance tests, I'd compare the above version with this variation:

```
SELECT l.LabID, l.LabName, LabUsers = STUFF((SELECT N'•' + lu.LabUserName
  FROM dbo.LabUsers AS lu 
  WHERE lu.LabID = l.LabID
  ORDER BY lu.LabUserName
  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.Labs AS l;
```

On my system I see the initial version at the top of this answer to be far more expensive. Also note that stuffing (no pun intended) these approaches into a user-defined function will bring it closer to the concatenation method @RThomas proposed.

Comment: This is actually a pretty common pattern to a frequently asked question. This FOR XML PATH subquery works like GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL - for each value of LabID it builds up a string consisting of each lab user found.

Comment: Curious how my answer performs compared to yours... I've used the coalesce approach several times but MVPs like yourself seem to always like the xml path approach.

Comment: @RThomas well, you can always compare them. :-) I suspect the UDF called per row will add some overhead as well.

Comment: Good point ;-) just me trying to access the RAM in your head as opposed to the disk I/O available to mine.  But I am curious so I will.

Comment: I setup a table with 1000 parents, 3000 children and tested.  Your way was 16 ms and my way was 312 ms - both approaches used a clean query cache and the same server, test data. You win for now +1. :)

Comment: @RThomas thanks for the confirmation. Then again, the difference you highlight might be largely irrelevant until you get into very large datasets, and particularly with a one-time operation.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

```
SELECT  LabName ,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + LabUsers.LabUserName
                FROM    dbo.LabUsers
                WHERE   LabUsers.LabID = Labs.LabID
                ORDER BY LabName
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') AS Labusers
FROM    dbo.Labs
ORDER BY LabName
```

The FOR XML PATH('') concatenates your strings together into one XML result and the STUFF puts a "nothing" character at the first character, e.g. wipes out the unneeded first comma.

Comment: +1 for you too since it was roughly the same approach as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is set up a UDF that returns all the lab users as a single string like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LabUserString
(
@pLabId Int
)
RETURNS NVarChar(Max)
AS
BEGIN

  Declare @pResult NVarChar(Max)

  SELECT @pResult = COALESCE(@pResult + N'•', '') + [LabUserName] 
  FROM LabUsers WHERE LabId = @pLabId

  Return @pResult

END
```

And then a query like this:

```
Select LabID, LabName, dbo.LabUserString(LabID) AS LabUsers FROM Labs
```

Comment: I'll leave the answer for posterity, but my own tests showed the accepted answer to perform better.  Quite a bit actually.